# How can I output each item of a multiple list custom field

Tags: custom-field, array

**print_r($item->jcfields);**

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Specialisms
            [name] => specialisms
            [checked_out] => 0
            [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [note] => 
            [state] => 1
            [access] => 1
            [created_time] => 2018-06-16 18:01:45
            [created_user_id] => 903
            [ordering] => 0
            [language] => *
            [fieldparams] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [multiple] => 1
                            [options] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [options0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => General Personal Training
                                            [value] => General Personal Training
                                        )

                                    [options1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Conditioning
                                            [value] => Conditioning
                                        )

                                    [options2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Strength
                                            [value] => Strength
                                        )

                                    [options3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Boxing
                                            [value] => Boxing
                                        )

                                    [options4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Rugby
                                            [value] => Rugby
                                        )

                                    [options5] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Football
                                            [value] => Football
                                        )

                                    [options6] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => High Intensity Training (HIT)
                                            [value] => High Intensity Training (HIT)
                                        )

                                    [options7] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Long Distance Running
                                            [value] => Long Distance Running
                                        )

                                    [options8] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Athletics
                                            [value] => Athletics
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [initialized:protected] => 1
                    [separator] => .
                )

            [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [render_class] => 
                            [class] => 
                            [showlabel] => 1
                            [show_on] => 
                            [display] => 0
                            [display_readonly] => 2
                        )

                    [initialized:protected] => 1
                    [separator] => .
                )

            [type] => list
            [default_value] => 
            [context] => com_contact.contact
            [group_id] => 0
            [label] => Specialisms
            [description] => 
            [required] => 0
            [language_title] => 
            [language_image] => 
            [editor] => 
            [access_level] => Public
            [author_name] => Eoin
            [group_title] => 
            [group_access] => 
            [group_state] => 
            [value] => General Personal Training, Conditioning, Strength, Boxing, Athletics
            [rawvalue] => Array
                (
                    [0] => General Personal Training
                    [1] => Conditioning
                    [2] => Strength
                    [3] => Boxing
                    [4] => Athletics
                )

        )

)
```

I can output the value by using

```
foreach ($item->jcfields as $field) {
   echo $field->value;
}
```

But how can I output the `options` 1 by 1.  Then I can style individual items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this so I could be wrong. But if I rightly remember, a protected object cannot be retrieved by `$field->fieldparams->options`. Instead, you'll need to use:

```
$options = $field->fieldparams->get('options');

foreach ($options as $option)
{
    echo $option->name;
    echo $option->value;
}
```

Again, I haven't tested this and have a feeling it might return a PHP error, but thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: That worked, cheers.

Comment: Oof, that was lucky :)

Comment: Well I wish I had that luck I'd ask a lot less questions on here

Answer (score 2):

The field options are a registry object so if you've already got the field you can grab all the options with something like:

```
$field_options = $field->fieldparams->toArray();
```

print_r that and you'll see the structure it provides which you can then just foreach through.

Comment: Awesome very helpful.  Is there any advantage or disadvantage of toArray vs the other answer using get?

Comment: The current code is https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/4.0-dev while an issues milestone is used to specify issues for j4 here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/milestone/5 also if you arent on the google group list then you should join that too.